# Netlogo Test Coordinates

Tags: netlogo

I defined my turtles as:

```
breed[ persons person] 
breed[ commerces commerce]
```

// commerce is supermarket for exemple.

Supermarkets are fix (stable) and the person go to the market to buy something.

my Question is : how to count how many people go to the supermarket and the
supermarket must know how many persons passed by.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you'll need to keep a commerce variable.

Somewhere in your code you'd need to increment the variable based on how many people were at the store. Assuming that people leave immediately (as to not double dip), this will do the trick.

```
commerces-own [ people-visited]

...
to go
   ask commerces [ set people-visited people-visited + count persons-here]
end
```